# Function to make copy of 2nd page of PDF(s) is failing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not sure if this is possible with Google Apps Script. However, I want to create a function that takes one of my Google Drive folders (which is full of PDFs), gets the second page of each PDF only, and makes a copy. (The reason for this task is that I want to send automated emails with the 2nd page of each PDF only).

I have the function below, which does indeed loop through the PDFs, but is not making a copy of page 2. It is only making a copy of the entire PDF file.

```
function copySecondPageOfPDFs() {

  const folderId = "MY FOLDER ID";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();

    if (file.getMimeType() === "application/pdf") {

      const pdfBlob = file.getBlob();

      const resource = {
        title: file.getName() + "_Page_2.pdf",
        mimeType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const params = {
        method: "post",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
        payload: pdfBlob,
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media",
        params
      );

      const newFileId = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).id;
      const newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);
      
      folder.addFile(newFile);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to make this work. Thanks to a Medium post from Tanaike. I will develop this logic and post my answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `I figured out how to make this work. Thanks to a Medium post from Tanaike. I will develop this logic and post my answer soon.` of your comment, I guessed that you might see [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/exporting-specific-pages-from-a-pdf-as-a-new-pdf-using-google-apps-script-2f22d07b4618). If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

- In this case, the specific page is exported from a PDF file using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) of the Javascript library. So, it is required to load or copy and paste this library into the Google Apps Script project.
- I thought that in your situation, `getFilesByType` might be able to be used instead of `getFiles`. In this case, only PDF files can be retrieved.
- In the case of `uploadType=media`, the file metadata cannot be included.
- The methods of `addFile` and `removeFile` of Class Folder have already been deprecated. Please be careful about this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#deprecated-methods_1)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set `const folderId = "MY FOLDER ID";`.

```js
async function myFunction() {
  const pageNumbers = [2]; // In this sample, the page 2 is exported as a PDF.
  const folderId = "MY FOLDER ID"; // Please set your folder ID.

  // Load pdf-lib.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  };

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const pdfBlob = file.getBlob();
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(pdfBlob.getBytes()));
    const numberOfpages = pdfData.getPageCount();
    if (numberOfpages > 1) {
      const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(numberOfpages)].map((_, i) => i));
      pages.forEach((page, i) => {
        if (pageNumbers.includes(i + 1)) {
          pdfDoc.addPage(page);
        }
      });
      const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      folder.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, `${file.getName()}_Page_2.pdf`));
    } else {
      console.log(`"${file.getName()}" has only 1 page.`);
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the PDF files are retrieved, and when the PDF file has more than 2 pages, only page 2 is exported as a new PDF file. And, the created PDF file is put into the same folder as the searched folder.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the pdf-lib library is loaded in the script. But, of course, in this case, you can also use the pdf-lib library by copying and pasting the script library retrieved from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js` in the script editor of Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost for loading it can be reduced.

#### References:

- [Exporting Specific Pages From a PDF as a New PDF Using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/exporting-specific-pages-from-a-pdf-as-a-new-pdf-using-google-apps-script-2f22d07b4618)
- [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! I have currently just included the link into my script. I have a question about using the pdf-lib as a Library. To make it work, do I create a new script file, paste the info from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js" and then import it as a library into my scritp?

Comment: @Borgher Thank you for replying. About `To make it work, do I create a new script file, paste the info from "cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js" and then import it as a library into my scritp?`, as I mentioned in my answer when you want to include pdf-lib in your Google Apps Script, please copy and paste the script of `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js` in the same Google Apps Script of the above script. And, please remove `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText())`. By this, you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are not modifying the PDF to copy only the second page. To achieve this, you can use a library called "PDF-LIB" within your Google Apps Script project. Here's an updated version of your code that includes the necessary modifications:
Please ensure that you've added the "PDF-LIB" library to your project using the script ID 1O_w0OH2uRv0vQOQm9XW0UhXPxkdvY9hwH9Uia6qFeuIDQVnpujgw4n.

```
// Add the PDF-LIB library to your project (Resources > Libraries, add the library with the following script ID: 1O_w0OH2uRv0vQOQm9XW0UhXPxkdvY9hwH9Uia6qFeuIDQVnpQOujgw4n)
// This library allows manipulation of PDF files in Google Apps Script

function copySecondPageOfPDFs() {
  const folderId = "MY FOLDER ID";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();

    if (file.getMimeType() === "application/pdf") {
      const pdfBlob = file.getBlob();
      const pdfBytes = pdfBlob.getBytes();

      const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);

      // Get the second page of the PDF document
      const [secondPage] = pdfDoc.getPages().slice(1); // Index 1 represents the second page

      const newPdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
      newPdfDoc.addPage(secondPage);

      const newPdfBytes = await newPdfDoc.save();

      const resource = {
        title: file.getName() + "_Page_2.pdf",
        mimeType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const params = {
        method: "post",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
        payload: newPdfBytes,
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media",
        params
      );

      const newFileId = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).id;
      const newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);

      folder.addFile(newFile);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! For some reason when I go to my script, click "Add A Library" and put in the script ID, it says: Unable to look up library. Check the ID and access permissions and try again.